# How to avoid edit war?

Tags: support, editing

Participant A suggested I remove a particular paragraph from an [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/85265/32436) I wrote; I explained why I was choosing to leave that paragraph in my answer; then Participant B *removed* the paragraph on his own initiative.

I don't want to provoke an edit war, but I want to reinstate the paragraph.  What's the best way to get the paragraph back in without escalating the conflict?  In other words, is it okay to just do a rollback, or does that risk escalation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, an edit removing a piece of advice is an edit that is conflicting with the intents of the author and thus not permissible. Therefore you have every right to insist on this paragraph. Of course you have to live with being downvoted or even flagged as a result.

With your specific edit, one could argue that it does not address the question and thus can and should be removed. I do not think that this is the right approach since we allow for such extra advice in general. If somebody think that such extra advice is harmful or too much, they can express this via comments and votes.

In summary, I think that you are fully allowed to restore that paragraph.